# Closed question reappears at the top

Tags: support, closed-questions

Why is a closed question brought back at the top by *Community*?

[image]

I might be wrong, but it really doesn't make sense. Even less since it was closed as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was bumped because an edit was made to one of the answers by an anonymous user (which I approved). Edits to answers bump the question.

There was no indication that the question was closed on the suggested edits page, otherwise I would have rejected the edit.

Actually looking again at the edit in context it appears to be spam anyway, so I'm going to roll it back.